# Sum dependant on another sum

Tags: summation, wolfram-alpha

I want to calculate the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{\lambda_1^k\exp(-\lambda_1)}{k!}(1-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{n!}exp(-\lambda_2 x)(\lambda_2 x)^n)$$

Wolfram Alpha seems to be having trouble with the second summation, I think the problem is that the stopping point of the second summation depends on the first summation. Is Wolfram Alpha able to solve this summation or is there different software I can use?

Comment: In the second sum, factor out $\exp(-\lambda)$. The result doesn't have a particularly nice form and is known as the [exponential sum function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html).

Comment: Ok, but that form still has summations dependant on a variable. Unless Wolfram Alpha has a function for the gamma function.

Comment: My point was that I doubt there is a good closed form unless maybe rearranging the order of the sums does something.

Comment: Well Wolfram Alpha doesn't really need a good closed form to do calculations?

Comment: WA can't do everything mate, and if the input/calculations get too complicated it'll quit on you.

Comment: John: Just to be clear, in the inner sum the term $(\lambda_2 x)^n$ is not an input to the $exp$ function?

Comment: @coffeemath Correct.